# Access elements of table through row number in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html-table

I have a PHP script that generates table rows with hidden input tags that have names like title1,  title2 etc and price1,  price2 etc. The user has the ability to remove and add rows as they see fit. My question is when I submit the rows how can I read those hidden inputs in order, either through PHP or Javascript?

EDIT: Sorry about the lack of detail. Here's some code:

The PHP that generates the rows

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
$i=0;
while ($list = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$i++;
$title = $list['title'];
$price = $list['price'];
$plu = $list['plu'];

?>

<tr id="row<?php echo $i; ?>"><td><input type="hidden" name="title<?php echo $i; ?>"     value="<?php echo $title; ?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="price<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $price; ?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="plu<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $plu; ?>">        </td></tr>

<?php
}
?>
```

Now if users can remove rows, I know I can tell exactly how many rows there are, but when it comes time to read them and save them in order I'm lost.

Comment: can you give a table row example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you're guaranteed to get them in order based on location on the page, but since you can name the elements yourself, you could name them `title[1]`, `title[2]`, ...

For example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="title[1]" value="foo">
...
<input type="hidden" name="title[2]" value="bar">
```

This will allow you to access the submitted elements in PHP by, for example:

```
$_POST['title'][1], $_POST['title'][2], etc.
```

Comment: of via a loop, like `for` or `while`

Comment: And when I need to access them how am I to know how many rows there are?

Comment: `count($_GET['title'])` should give you what you want.  You can iterate through them by something like `foreach($_GET['title'] as $k=>$v){ /* do something with $_GET['title'][$k] */ }`

Comment: but if row 2 is removed then I'll be reading in row 2 as empty data won't I?

Comment: If row 2 is removed then a foreach loop like I suggested above will "skip" 2 -- that is, it will never set $k to 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one or two (for title and price) hidden input rather separate inputs for each values...all you need to do is use some special characters like ';','#' as a delemeter to seperate each values.. and when user delete the row just remove that value from the entire string....you can do it easily using javascript..

so ultimately you will have to submit only one (or two) hidden values...

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to store and then read them out individually?